# Completely disable RSS feeds on WP 5.5.2 and show a 404 page instead of die();

Tags: functions, 404-error, rss, code

I'd like to completely disable RSS feeds on my WP website. Can someone please guide me on how to throw a 404.php page and set the headers to 404, when someone types in `https://example.com/feed/`

here is the code in functions.php:

```
function disable_feeds() {    
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->is_feed = false;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();
    wp_die( __('No feed available,please visit our <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>!') );
}
 
add_action( 'do_feed',      'disable_feeds', 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_rdf',  'disable_feeds', 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss',  'disable_feeds', 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'disable_feeds', 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_atom', 'disable_feeds', 1 );

add_action( 'do_feed_rss2_comments', 'disable_feeds', 1 );
add_action( 'do_feed_atom_comments', 'disable_feeds', 1 );

add_action( 'feed_links_show_posts_feed',    '__return_false', 1 );
add_action( 'feed_links_show_comments_feed', '__return_false', 1 );
```

Strangely, I get a 500 Internal Server Error when typing `https://example.com/feed/`

no corresponding rules are set in `.htaccess` file
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the HTTP Response code in `wp_die` function.

```php
wp_die( __('No feed available,please visit our <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>!'), '', 404 );
```

Answer (score 2):

If I want to bail out of my WP, I do it like this:

```
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 );
    exit();
```

I'm actually not sure, why you get a 500 error. I'd try to comment out the lines of your function one-by-one and see, where the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I followed your instructions. This has resolved the Error 500. However, the browser keeps thinking it is still an RSS feed by not displaying the HTML page and prompting to open a RSS reader app.. Any ideas how fix that?

Comment: Hm, I found this on the web, but looks pretty much the same, as you already have. ```function wpb_disable_feed() {
wp_die( __('No feed available,please visit our <a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'">homepage</a>!') );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'wpb_disable_feed', 1);```

Comment: Additionally, you can remove the header lines `remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );`

Comment: https://wpcaptain.com/blog/how-to-disable-rss-feeds-completely-in-wordpress/ This seems to be the most complete one... It even shows, how to block them via .htaccess .

Comment: thanks very much for the link. I saw it before. However, that solution uses a redirect to home url, and it will generate a 301 header, not 404. Do you know if it will have any impact on SEO and search engine crawlers? I've read somewhere it is better not to use a redirect...

I guess, I will have to restrict the access via `.htaccess` as per the solution above

Comment: True, using 301 redirect seems not the best option. I have no idea, how that would impact SEO. Should not be a big deal. 301s happen all the time. But in this case a 404 would be much better.