# How do you modify HTTP response headers on feed/?

Tags: headers, http

Trying to change `Content-Type: application/rss+xml` to `Content-Type: something/else` on example.com/feed/.

My code so far:

```
function force_404() {
    global $wp_query;

    // Modify content-type header here, nothing I've tried works

    status_header(404);
    nocache_headers();
    include(get_query_template('404'));
    die();
}

add_action('do_feed', 'force_404', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'force_404', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'force_404', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'force_404', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'force_404', 1);
```

I initially thought the problem was the headers were already sent, but the 404 works, so that tells me they're still modifiable here. I'm at the end of my rope. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

My goal is to make the /feed/ 404 page render actual text/html in the browser instead of application/rss+xml, which renders as plain text. Changing the `content-type` header to `text/html` should do the trick.

**Edit 2**

It may not be possible to do this on `/feed/`, [here is my evidence](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/377379/). I'm going to hold out hope that someone can confirm or deny.

Comment: Are you just trying to disable feeds?

Comment: Nosir, trying to do something else entirely

Comment: what are you trying to do? Changing the http header is unlikely to be the solution you hoped, but that doesn't mean your task is impossible. Why are you trying to force the 404 page for feeds?

Comment: I want to make it so when the 404 page renders, it displays `content-type: text/html` instead of `content-type: application/rss+xml`. This will make the page render actual HTML instead of printing the HTML code.

Comment: @Jeff, that didn't really answer Tom's question, so once again, what are you really trying to do? What do you actually want to display at `/feed`? A WordPress 404 page? Why? Are you doing this just for `/feed` or `feed/<anything>` like `/feed/atom`? How would people subscribe to your site's feeds, because your code is essentially disabling feeds, except that you're disabling it by serving a 404 page? 

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, show a 404 page with rendered HTML (instead of plain/text) on all WP feed pages.

Comment: In that case, you might want to just intercept the request without using those `do_feed` action hooks, but once again, the `feed_content_type` filter can indeed be used for the purpose of setting a different content type header for feeds, so you can try sending a HEAD request to the `/feed` URL and just check the value of the `Content-Type` header. You can also use an online tool such as https://httpstatus.io/..

Comment: Thanks @SallyCH, would you mind posting an answer? I'm not sure how to intercept the request and put it all together. The 404 part works perfectly, it's setting the content-type header I don't know how to do in WP. I'm a fairly advanced PHP coder and I know more than I care to admit about HTTP headers.

Comment: Done, @Jeff. (PS: It's "CJ" and not "CH"..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the `Content-Type` header, then the `feed_content_type` filter can indeed be used for that purpose. <sub>(If your code isn't changing the header, then another code might have overridden that header, so you can try using a lower priority for your filter callback)</sub>

But there's another filter hook you can use, namely [`wp_headers`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/). You can use it to change/remove the response headers set by WordPress on *any pages*.

So for example, for feed requests (`/feed`, `/feed/atom`, `/comments/feed`, etc.), WordPress sets the `Content-Type`, `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers, hence you can change/remove any of that headers using the `wp_headers` filter.

However, as for what you're trying to do — display a WordPress's 404 page when the request is for a feed, a simpler way to do that is by using the [`parse_request` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) to *change the request to a non-feed request and then set the `error` query var to 404* which then automatically intructs WordPress to show a 404 error page.

**Working Example**

```php
add_action( 'parse_request', 'my_disable_feed_request' );
function my_disable_feed_request( $wp ) {
    // If it's a feed request, empty the `feed` query var and then make
    // WordPress shows a 404 error page by setting the `error` to 404.
    if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['feed'] ) ) {
        $wp->query_vars['feed']  = '';
        $wp->query_vars['error'] = '404';
    }
}
```

So with that, you don't need to use the code in question, and actually, those `do_feed` hooks would no longer run because the feed request has been intercepted.

Note though, the above code will apply to any [core WordPress feed URLs](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/wordpress-feeds/#finding-your-feed-url), so if you want the code to apply to the main feeds only, you can check if the request path starts with `feed/` or that it's exactly `feed`, like so:

```php
if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['feed'] ) && preg_match( '#^feed(/|$)#', $wp->request ) )
```

Comment: You are awesome. Being somewhat new to WP, I need to learn which variables to access (in a plugin context) and I'll be up and running in no time. Can you give me a nudge in the right direction to intercept requests for `/wp-json`.

Comment: You can basically use the `parse_request` hook (which is also used by WordPress core to handle `/wp-json` requests), however, I can only give a better or further insight after knowing what routes are you wanting to intercept and why so (because there could be a better solution than intercepting the request). So, perhaps you want to post a new question for that? But you should first check the [REST API handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) because you might find something that can help you with whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your edit looks like you've got the filter concept reversed. Instead of `apply_filters( 'feed_content_type', 'atom' );`, try something like

```
add_filter( 'feed_content_type', 'wpse415005_change_feed_type', 10, 2 );
function wpse415005_change_feed_type( $content_type, $type ) {
     if ( 'rss' === $type || 'rss2' === $type ) {
          $content_type = 'something/else';
     }
     return $content_type;
}
```

### References

- [feed_content_type (filter hook)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/feed_content_type/)
- [feed_content_type() (function)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/feed_content_type/)

Comment: I appreciate that, Pat. I removed that edit so I don't muddy the waters. I put a more descriptive explanation in my comment above.

Comment: I'd recommend including that information in the question, too. That way, even if the comment thread grows long, your purpose will still be clear in the question itself.

Comment: @Jeff this filter (`feed_content_type`) is indeed the WordPress way of setting a different content type header at `/feed`. Have you actually tried this along with the code in your post? If yes and it didn't work, try reloading the page? (Or clear your caches)

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, yes I did a hard reload bypassing the cache. Yes I actually tried it (many times, many variations). I think the problem is the `feed/` content-type header is deeply hard-coded into WP. I'm sending the correct header, but WP is just not accepting it. Could also be the timing of sending my custom header, but I need a WP expert/dev to tell me.